# VBA Printing ranges from different sheets and prompting the user only once

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 ranges (fixed) in 2 different sheets which I want to print in a single file in different pages, prompting the user by the Print dialogue box only once.

I am so far doing this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$D$47"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$D$94"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
```

But it doesn't even prompts the user even once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select multiple sheets at once, then call the `PrintOut` command.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$D$47"

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$D$94"

Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintPreview
Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'Needed so that multiple sheets don't remain selected
```

Comment: Okay, This seems fine, but I am not getting even a single dialogue box still, how do I choose the printer on the fly?

Comment: Ah, edited to `.PrintPreview` instead of `.PrintOut` that should allow printer selection.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to copy the cells into a new sheet, set the page breaks and then use the `.PrintPreview` method to show the print preview where they can change settings and call the print dialog if they choose.

Comment: Isn't there a way to select multiple ranges and print them using a single job.

Comment: No.  There is no `Range(...).Print` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
'I was able to print to four named ranges with this code 

If msgbox1 = vbOK Then
    Worksheets("TP print").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "TP_1A1,TP_1A2,TP_1A3,TP_1A4"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Preview:=Preview
    Worksheets("TP Orders").Activate  ' Return to Enter Order screen
Else
    MsgBox "Print Operation cancelled"
       Exit Sub
End If

'Just give range names to the sections you want to print.
```